# How to find the function behind a button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

There's this website that's basically a stopwatch and on the website, you can click a button to remove you're last recorded time. However, I want to find the function that runs when I press the button so I can just enter the function in the chrome console and remove it that way. I'm not sure if this is possible or if I was clear enough but thanks in advance.

Comment: check onclick attribute or event listeners attached to the element

Comment: Do you mean the onclick in the html or css? Cause the button is `<input type="button" data="d" value="X">` and I can't find anything on event listeners

Answer (score 2):

on second photo you will see a button upside called pretty click that to make code readable

[image]

[image]